# Why does the Z-Spinning direction change when a ball bounce?

Tags: forces, torque

Today I was playing with a hand-sized ball (not really relevant) and what I was doing was to grab the ball from the upper hemisphere and drop it while doing a motion that gave it a clockwise spin movement.
After doing this a couple of times, I noticed that after the first bounce the ball was spinning counterclockwise, then it bounced again and was spinning clockwise... and so on.

What causes this effect?

EDIT:
Originally, it said Y-Spinning instead of Z-Spinning.
For a more accurate description check out Derek's comment

Comment: This effect is also familiar to—and used strategically by—players of tennis, ping pong and other games where bouncing a ball off a surface is common.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that mentioned somewhere else.
I think it's worth mention that I made a mistake and it's not the Y axis but the Z axis. I was thinking in a 2D system.

Comment: I need some clarification.  So in your coordinate system, the ball is falling in the Z-direction , the ground/floor is the XY plane, and when you drop it you rotate it in the negative direction about the Z-axis (this would give it a clockwise rotation from an observer above the ball looking down)?  And then after etch bounce it has changed the direction it's spinning?

Comment: @Derek Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's what he means (I noticed this a long time ago as well).

Comment: @Derek yes, that's what I meant. I did a bad explanation from the beginning.

Comment: OK, I think @Compa has the correct explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand why this happens. I asked my boss and he told me "It's because it's flexible" So I tried this with a golf ball (earlier I was playing with a racquetball) and the ball kept spinning in the same direction after every bounce.

I will need someone to confirm if this is the reason but I speculate that, as the ball hits the ground, the shape absorbs the force/energy/magic that is making it spin CW and "the shape twists in that direction" (as if you were twisting a string) then the ball "untwists" and this gives the force necessary for the ball to spin CCW. This does not happen on harder balls because they do not flex, absorbing the force and twisting the shape.

At least, that's what I think

Comment: Elasticity is half the answer. But there is a second part.

Comment: @dmckee I'm guessing you're eluding to friction?

Comment: Bingo. There has to be a mechanism to store and return rotational energy (elasticity) and a force along the plane of contact (friction) that actually does the work of storing and then returning the energy.

Comment: I think the golf ball with its harder surface will grip the floor less, so it possibly slips on the floor and continues to spin the same way. Golf balls may be hard but they are surprisingly elastic and they do deform when hit by a golf club. Compare with a rubber bouncy ball which will grip the floor very well, braking the spinning motion and storing its energy in the elastic rubber, then un-twisting the other way.

Comment: @user2800708 I think it's a combination of both.  It doesn't deform as much, or have as much friction so it has less area and less friction to twist.

Comment: I see, the degree of deformation will affect the size of its 'footprint' and therefore how well it grips the floor - good point.

Comment: @user2800708 Not only how well it grips; odds are the wider area will be able to apply greater torque (bigger radius).